# Recursively running a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a function in MySQL that needs to be run about 50 times (not a set value) in a query. the inputs are currently stored in an array such as 
 `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

when executing the MySQL query individually it's working fine, please see below

`column_name` denotes the column it's getting the data for, in this case, it's a DOUBLE in the database

The second value in the `MOD()` function is the input I'm supplying MySQL from the aforementioned array

```
SELECT id, MOD(column_name, 4) AS mod_output
FROM table
HAVING mod_output > 10
```

To achieve the output I require* the following code works

```
SELECT id, MOD(column_name, 4) AS mod_output1, MOD(column_name, 5) AS mod_output2, MOD(column_name, 6) AS mod_output3
FROM table
HAVING mod_output1 > 10 AND mod_output2 > 10 AND mod_output3 > 10
```

However this obviously is extremely dirty, and when having not 3 inputs, but over 50, this will become highly inefficient.

Appart from calling over 50 individual querys, is there a better way to acchieve the *same sort* (see below) of output?

In escennce i need to supply MySQL with a list of values and have it run `MOD()` over all of them on a specified column.

The only data I need returned is the `id`'s of the rows that match the `MOD()` functions output with the specified input (see value 2 of the `MOD()` function) where the output is less than 10

*Please note, `MOD()` has been used as an example function, however, the final function required *should* be a drop in replacement*

example table layout

```
id | column_name
1  | 0.234977
2  | 0.957739
3  | 2.499387
4  | 48.395777
5  | 9.943782
6  | -39.234894
7  | 23.49859
.....
```

(The title may be worded wrong, I'm not quite sure how else you'd explain what I'm trying to do here)

Comment: While creating query in the application code, you can put the function call part in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join` and derived table or temporary table:

```
SELECT n.n, t.id, MOD(t.column_name, n.n) AS mod_output
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 4 as n UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 . . .
     ) n
WHERE MOD(t.column_name, n.n) > 10;
```

If you want the results as columns, you can use conditional aggregation afterwards.